# Handling &amp as character in URL

Tags: php, url

I'm making a site to learn coding and am making a search site. The search is `$q`.

```
$q = ucwords(mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_REQUEST['q'])));
```

Then I am trying to put a link to other words the user might want to search. Unfortunately, if a word is "Example & Another Example", `$q` is only "Example", and the rest is left out. In the url this works (as in nothing is left out) *example+%26+another+example*
but this doesn't work Example%20&%20Another Example 
.

I tried using str_replace to replace all of the `&amp` with `%26` but it just made the `$q = null`. What's the issue?

Here's my code:

```
echo "<hr /><span><strong>Refine Search</strong><br/><br/>";
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM subcat WHERE catnumber='1' LIMIT 0,10");
$subcaturl = str_replace("&amp;", "%26", $row['subcat']);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<a href='search.php?q=". $subcaturl ."'/>" . $row['subcat'] ."</a>";
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Comment: Obligatory reference to using [mysqli_*](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) commands instead of mysql.

Comment: Nicely handled, Ryven, might need a `PDO` clause :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php):

```
$subcaturl = urlencode($row['subcat']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at urlencode / urldecode - that will help this problem.

Answer (score 0):

PHP will treat the '&' as the beginning of a new parameter.
In order to get the '&' as part of the q string, the user submitted data needs to be escaped of '&' before being placed in the URL string.

You can do this as an example :

```
str_replace ('&", "-", $row['subcat']);
```

Also you can try encoding and decoding the url

```
urlencode($row['subcat']);
urldecode($row['subcat']);
```